# finding difference iphone 4s and 5 working wrongly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

configh.h

```
#define IS_IPHONE5  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568
```

homeViewController.m

```
- ( void ) phoneType{

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 568){
            NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
            homeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Home.fw.png"];
            loginImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.fw.png"];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"iPhone 4S");
            homeImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-Home.png"];
            loginImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];            
        }
    }
```

This is the way iphone 4s and 5 i find difference.When i execute this code on iphone 5 log  iphone 4s printed.how do i change my code to get execute correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for the same:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
        // iPhone Classic
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        // iPhone 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This only works if you have at least added a `Default-568h@2x.png` launch image to your application. Else this will always return false. (Because the screen will be letterboxed if you don't have the launch image)

Also you might want to change the iPhone 5 check to

```
bool isIphone5 = (([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] 
== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && (([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * 
[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]) >= 1136));
```

Because of floating point issues with == and !=

Comment: i am using simulator 5.1 and xcode 4.3.2 and os 10.7.3.will ur code work for me?

Comment: The code will compile but will always return false if used with Xcode 4.3.2, since the `Default-568h@2x.png` launch image only works when compiled with XCode 4.5 and up

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate rule of math in C: never use `==` and `!=` with floating-point numbers. They don't work as you would expect it. Instead of checking it to be a specific value, check for being less or more than an intermediate value:

```
IS_IPHONE5 ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > 500)
```

Also, it's advisable to always parenthesize your macros.

Comment: It's perfectly valid, defined and deterministic to compare floats using `==`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I didn't say it's invalid or non-deterministic, it can just produce surprising results if one does not know how it works.

Comment: The (bad old) advice not to compare floats directly is misleading in many situations and produces less readable code. In your example you softened the precise condition ("is the screen 568pt high?") to some less understandable "more than 500pt". There's no reason for doing so. `float` numbers can represent integers in the range ±2^23 without loss of precision. Comparisons are always precise. Calculations that have a result that can be precisely represented are guaranteed to have no rounding errors (`10.0f/5.0f == 2.0f`).